# How to fit parametric equations to data points in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am looking for a way to fit
[parametric equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) to a set of data points, using Python.

As a simple example, given is the following set of data points:

```
import numpy as np
x_data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y_data = np.array([2, 0, 3, 7, 13])
```

Using `t` as the parameter, I want to fit the following parametric equation to the data points,

```
t = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
x = a1*t + b1
y = a2*t**2 + b2*t + c2
```

that is, have Python find the values for the coefficients `a1`, `b1`, `a2`, `b2`, `c2` that fits `(x,y)` best to the data points `(x_data, y_data)`.

Note that the `y(t)` and `x(t)` functions above only serve as examples of parametric equations. The actual functions I want to fit my data to are much more complex, and in those functions, it is not trivial to express `y` as a function of `x`.

Help will be appreciated - thank you!

Comment: I have tried to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. The problem is that `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`requires (as far as I know) `y`as a function of `x`.

In my problem, I have a parametric equation with both `y` and `x` as a function of `t`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use polyfit, but please take care that the length of t must match the length of data points

```
import numpy as np

tt = np.linspace(0, 5, len(x_data))

x_params = np.polyfit(tt, x_data, 1)
y_params = np.polyfit(tt, y_data, 2)
```

Change the third parameter to the degree that you think fits your data.

To get the function you can use

```
y = np.poly1d(y_params)

t = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)

plot(t, y(t))
plot(tt, y_data, 'o')
```

Comment: The author said that the equations were more complex than the simple polynomials given. This won't work for the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Since the relation between `x` and `y` is a quadratic one, you can use `np.polyfit` to get the coefficients.
According to your equations, your `x` and `y` relation is:

`y = a2*((x-b1)/a1)**2 + b2*((x-b1)/a1) + c2`

Using polyfit, we get

```
y_data = np.array([2, 0, 3, 7, 13])
x_data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
np.polyfit(x_data,y_data,2)
[p2,p1,p0] = list(array([ 1.21428571, -4.38571429,  4.8       ]))
```

The values of `a1, b1, a2, b2, c2` can be obtained by solving the following eqns

`p2 = a2/a1**2`

`p1 = -2b1*a2/a1**2 + b2/a1`

`p0 = a2*b1**2/a1**2 -b2*b1/a1 + c2`

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. However, in my actual problem, there is no trivial way to find a relation between `x`and `y`, and I would want to fit a parametric equation to my data points. The `x` and `y` functions I provided here serve only as a simple example - sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Well, then the answer below is correct, assuming that you know what the values of the array `t` are.