# Extracting a laser line in an image (using OpenCV)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, line, detection

i have a picture from a laser line and i would like to extract that line out of the image.

[image]

As the laser line is red, i take the red channel of the image and then searching for the highest intensity in every row:

[image]

The problem now is, that there are also some points which doesnt belong to the laser line (if you zoom into the second picture, you can see these points).

Does anyone have an idea for the next steps (to remove the single points and also to extract the lines)?

That was another approach to detect the line: 
First i blurred out that "black-white" line with a kernel, then i thinned(skeleton) that blurred line to a thin line, then i applied an OpenCV function to detect the line.. the result is in the below image:[image]

***NEW:***

Now i have another harder situation.
I have to extract a green laser light.
  The problem here is that the colour range of the laser line is wider and changing.
On some parts of the laser line the pixel just have high green component, while on other parts the pixel have high blue component as well.
[image]

Comment: The problem is that you take the one with the highest in every row. So you will always get a point per line. Maybe you can threshold base on the value (e.g. if the Red component is bigger than 100). You may still get other Red objects or point in the image. Also you should take in account the values from blue and green components, for example, white is (255,255,255) so all of them are high. You should take those values which have red high and other channels quite low. Also you can use line detection algorithms afterwards to filter other blobs

Comment: i exactly did do this already (taking just the pixel where red is high, but green and blue quite low)

Comment: You can also try dilate and erode since the line points are quite together, and the noise points are not. Or try the [Hough line transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) to obtain only the lines, but I am not sure if the curved line will be detected.

Comment: remember that a pure white has a high R value, too! Make sure that G and B aren't that high and/or use HSV color space.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the best to use the YCrCb color space because the Cr part is representing the red component of the image in a more intense way?

Comment: If you need accuracy, you may consider sub-pixel evaluation: https://hackaday.io/project/4034-importworld/log/13556-sub-pixel-laser-line-detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really sorry for the short answer without any code, but I suggest you take contours and process them.

I dont know exact what you need, so here are two approaches for you:

- just collect as much as possible contours on single line (use centers and try find straight line with smallest mean)
- as first way, but trying heuristically combine separated lines.... it's much harder, but this may give you almost full laser line from image.

--

Some example for yours picture:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
# filtering red area of hue
redHueArea = 15
redRange = ((hsv[:, :, 0] + 360 + redHueArea) % 360) 
hsv[np.where((2 * redHueArea) > redRange)] = [0, 0, 0] 
# filtering by saturation
hsv[np.where(hsv[:, :, 1] < 95)] = [0, 0, 0]
# convert to rgb
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
# select only red grayscaled channel with low threshold  
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 15, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
# contours processing
(_, contours, _) = cv2.findContours(gray.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, 1)
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 8: continue
    epsilon = 0.1 * cv2.arcLength(c, True) # tricky smoothing to a single line
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], -1, [255, 255, 255], -1)

cv2.imshow('result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

In your case it's work perfectly, but, as i already said, you will need to do much more work with contours.

[image]

Comment: I also already tried that.. you can see the results on the new image i posted now..

Comment: First thanks a lot! 
I just implemented your code in C++ and it's working quite reliable...
But for me it's more important to extract that *curved* line and not only an approximating straight line (because we want to use that line for a triangulation method to measure the distance to objects/ground)...
Do you have an idea how to extend it to extract that curve instead of a straight line?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406469/draw-a-curve-line-going-through-the-blobs-in-opencv/44410748#44410748 It's may be helpful for you too.

Answer (score 4):

Getting the highest value in every row will always output a value, instead of ignoring when the value isn't high enough. Consider using a threshold too, so that you can discard ones that aren't high enough.

However, that's not a very efficient way to do this at all. A much better and easier solution would be to use the OpenCV function [`inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange); define a lower and upper bound for the red color in all three channels, and this will return a binary image with white pixels where the image intensity is within that BGR range.

This is in python but it does the job, should be easy to see how to use the function:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.png')
lowerb = np.array([0, 0, 120])
upperb = np.array([100, 100, 255])
red_line = cv2.inRange(img, lowerb, upperb)

cv2.imshow('red', red_line)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This produces the output:
[image: Red line binary iamge]

This could be further processed by finding contours or other methods to turn the points into a nice curve.

Comment: First thanks a lot for your effort!
Till that step its very clear of course.. 
But the main problem is to detect the line/curve out of these points on the image you posted..
If i for example try to connect the nearest points together, i get a quite "zig-zag" line unfortunately...

Comment: You *can* use a polynomial fitting method, but otherwise, what exactly do you want to do with the line/curve? Do you need it as a binary image where the line is one pixel wide?

Comment: Yes, exactly! 
I want to get a curve / curves which are ideally 1 pixel wide.

Comment: @Mirnyy you can use a polynomial fitting method, but you'll have to parameterize it since the locations don't make a function with respect to `x` and `y`. OpenCV does not have curve fitting methods, you need a differently library. Similar python question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221050/how-to-fit-parametric-equations-to-data-points-in-python. I would open up a new question, as this isn't the question you asked. BTW you can easily extract the green laser line in HSV space and remove outliers with morphological operations good enough for fitting. [E.g.](http://imgur.com/irKdNIj)