# Draw a curve line going through the blobs in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am trying to draw a line that goes through the given blobs. The following is a given example

[image]

I want a curve line that goes through multiple blobs in horizontal direction as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is the green line? The purple lines? Do you want a straight line or a curve? Where's your code? What is the actual issue?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I edit the question with more information

Comment: still unclear, use a simplified example, draw what you want into the image. make sure you know the difference between blue and purple. you seem to mixe them up in your description. contours don't have outlines. they are outlines. also your image does not show contours. it shows a few blobs.

Comment: now I made it simple

Answer (score 1):

Just as example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
(_, contours, _) = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# biggest area
target = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))
cv2.drawContours(img, [target], -1, [0, 0, 255], -1) # debug
# just example of fitting
x = target[:, :, 0].flatten()
y = target[:, :, 1].flatten()
poly = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 5))
for _x in range(min(x), max(x), 5): # too lazy for line/curve :)
    cv2.circle(img, (_x, int(poly(_x))), 3, [0, 255, 0])

cv2.imshow('result', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: could you please write in C++ ? and I Also wanted to connect the blobs that are horizontally in the range of bigger blob.

Comment: Max, i'm sorry, but i have only Python + in C++ their is no numpy, so you need to search any libs for math calculations.

Comment: hey, no problem. thanks for your effort. Could you tel me how can I extand the line connected other blobs in horizontal direction ? as you can see the given image (the extanded line with blue color).

Comment: Easiest way - take all contours (concatenating theirs points), but it may look not very nice. Slightly harder/better way - calc biggest area (as I do), than filter other contours by mean distance to line and then recalculate curve by all remained contours.

Comment: what do you mean by "mean distance to line" ? Which point of line do I can use for distance calculation ?

Comment: i.e. take contour bounds rectangle, find nearest to approximated point of curve and check it distance. I'm sorry, but there is hundredths variants and it's very difficult to say something concretely.  Even provided by me code is *very* depend on picture. E. g., if biggest contour doesn't straight enough than approximated  curve will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks but I am still looking how can I implement it in C++

Comment: Create another question, put their  your code, describe what exact you can't implement and, at least I, suggest you something more exactly for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, and employing the **Perl** philosophy of *TMTOWTDI ("There's More Than One Way to Do It)"*, I extracted all the white points of your contours into a file called `points.dat` and fed that into `gnuplot` to fit a curve, which gave me a formula for a best fit line of:

```
y=3.10869110524588e-07*x*x*x -0.000972406154863963*x*x + 0.861790477479291*x + 307.220397010312
```

And then I plotted that in red on your original contours using **awk** and **ImageMagick**.

```
#!/bin/bash
convert contours.jpg -colorspace gray -threshold 50% txt: | awk -F: '/white/{print $1}' | tr ',' ' ' > points.dat
{ echo 'f(x) = a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x + d'; \
  echo 'fit f(x) "points.dat" via a, b, c, d'; \
  echo 'print a,"*u^3 + ",b,"*u^2 + ",c,"*u + ",d'; \
} | gnuplot 2>&1 | tail -1    

awk 'BEGIN{
     for(x=0;x<1504;x++){
        y=3.10869110524588e-07*x*x*x -0.000972406154863963*x*x + 0.861790477479291*x + 307.220397010312
        y=int(y)
        print "point ",x,y
     }
     }' /dev/null > p.mvg

convert contours.jpg -draw @p.mvg z.png
```

[image]

The start of `points.dat` looks like this:

```
769 453
770 453
771 453
772 453
773 453
769 454
765 455
766 455
767 455
768 455
...
...
```

The start of `p.mvg` looks like this:

```
fill red
point  0 307
point  1 308
point  2 308
point  3 309
point  4 310
point  5 311
point  6 312
point  7 313
point  8 314
...
...
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the implementation but Could you please let me know, how can I implement it in C++ or with Opencv ?

Comment: What is it that you are ultimately trying to achieve? Do you want a formula for the curve? Or do you want an image with a single-pixel wide line going through the contours? What will you do with the answer as the next step of your processing?

Comment: yes, I want a single pixel wide line going through the contours

Comment: and I have to give the line information that is going through the contours, to the machine.